# 500 Internal Server Error on page that exist

Tags: .htaccess

I am busy with a new WP site. So now and then I get a 500 Internal Server Error message when I goto http://www.myshop.com/en/my-account/
Probably caused by the WPML multi language plugin.

After a refresh all is okay.

How can I prevent this kind of errors.

Maybe something extra in .htaccess.
But what to write there?

Here the error log:
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://www.myshop.com/en/my-account/

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_vars 1660

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On 
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year" 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year" 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not enough information has been provided. Whenever you receive a 500 error, go directly to your server's error log to find more details about what went wrong. You could be experiencing a PHP error, or it could be a problem with your .htaccess (though that would not usually clear up on refresh). Check the error log and post the details here.

Comment: I have added it. See my additional info above

Comment: Ok, so that's a redirect loop. Something is probably wrong with your .htaccess. Again, we cannot help without seeing the contents of your .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already see what is going wrong. The domain holder is wrong declared. It has .com.com in the name. So I think this is the error maker. Thanks for replying.